# MobileFirst 7.1, nativeResources error for Window 8 Universal Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I am using MobileFirst studio **7.1.0.00-20151114-1616**, After Adding **Windows8 - Universal** Environment `nativeResources` folder is not created. And after creating `nativeResources` folder manually and press the build all environment option is throwing following error.

```
FWLST1040E: windows8 build failed: Failed copying nativeResources to native project (windows8)
```

What should I do? Is there any workaround for this?

**Edit 1:** There is one more problem, if I change the main file using application descriptor, it is not reflected in **package.appxmanifest** file in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this folder?

It is no longer recommended to use it in general other than to store static image files. This folder is also scheduled for removal in future versions, so I suggest that you will adjust to not using it.

Comment: What kind of platform dependent code? Web or native? Native code should go to the native folder.

Comment: But native folder is completely build with common resources when I press build all environment. And also need to put some web resources that are platform dependent

Comment: Well what's the problem? you the windows 8 folder and it has a js/css/images folders...

Comment: I have app which runs on all android, ios, and windows, but I need to have extra resources in Windows 8 and don't want to kept them in all the platforms.

Comment: You are not reading what I am writing. You added the Windows 8 Hybrid environments. Resources you put there are available only to that environments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100041/discussion-between-mo-ashfaq-and-idan-adar).

Comment: Where should I put class files and modified HTML file for platform, if I don't have nativeResources folder?

Comment: In the your-app\windows8 folder... it has a css, js and images folders. Those are the folders you need to use for environment-specific files. Please read the documentation.

Comment: Where should I kept modified native files like C# class files, package.appxmanifest etc.. Because they are overridden at every build.